# Tabulator - How to Clear a Selector Filter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm wondering how is it possible to clear a Filter using a Selector as used on the [Interactive Demo](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.0?#filter-header) for the **Gender** header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to add an empty option to a select header filter, then you just need to include a property in the ***headerFilterParams*** property with the value of an empty string:

```
{title:"Favourite Color", field:"color",   headerFilter:"select", headerFilterParams:{"":"", "red":"red", "green":"green"}}
```

If you want to trigger it programatically from outside the table then you can call ***setHeaderFilterValue*** on the column component

```
table.getColumn("color").setHeaderFilterValue("");
```

Comment: is it possible to ensure an order of the Select header filter? I am having problems with [JS Object Property Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: if you need to guarantee order then you can pass in an array instead of an object [{label:"Male", value:"male"},{label:"Female", value:"female"}]

Answer (score 0):

Much better option is to use

```
table.clearFilter(true);
```

This will clear all programmatically set filters, if you wisht to clear all header filters as well pass an argument of true to this function.

reference : http://tabulator.info/docs/5.2/filter#main-contents